# Winforms Drawing - Parameter is not valid on system resume

Tags: c#, winforms, exception, drawing

I have an odd problem when my app is running and the system resumes from hibernation (in Windows 7).

I am calling the Graphics.DrawString method and this works fine most of the time. Except when the program is running and I hibernate the system. Then when I resume, the DrawString method throws an ArgumentException (Parameter is not valid) and gives me a red cross where my drawing should be.

What is going wrong here? Catching the exception avoids the red cross but when we get into this state there is no way back and the exception will keep being thrown until the program is restarted.

Thanks for any help,
Alan

**Edit: Here is the code that is failing:**

```
protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
{
    // Drawing logic succeeds until this point

    e.Graphics.DrawString(Text, Font, new SolidBrush(ForeColor), new PointF(x, y));
}
```

This is actually a subclass of ToolStripLabel.

Comment: Can you add some code?  Make sure that the window that you were drawing on still exists.  It sounds like an invalid hWnd.

Comment: If you constructed a graphics object it might have become invalid as well.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, I've added a code sample. Something else I should mention is that the parent form is WPF with my Winforms components inside WindowsFormHost containers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many system resources become invalid after a sleep or hibernation. So your Font is probably invalid as that is a common cause of such issues. Also I note that you are not calling Dispose on the SolidBrush which you should do that to prevent resource leeks. Like this...

```
using(SolidBrush drawBrush = new SolidBrush(ForeColor))
    e.Graphics.DrawString(Text, Font, drawBrush, new PointF(x, y));
```

Comment: Thanks for your help Phil. It looks like not disposing the brush was the culprit. I've tried a couple of hibernates and the problem hasn't happened again.